# Not clear usage of “tous” and “toutes” as a determiner

Tags: grammaire, accord, déterminants

Which of the two is correct:

- *Tous les petites routes sont jolies*

or

- *Toutes les petites routes sont jolies*?

Google translate is making sentences out of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: **Toutes** is what you are looking for.

As per the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/)

> **Tout**, **toute**, **tous**, **toutes**
>   I. − Adjectif indéfini
>   B. − [Marque l'idée de totalité]
>   1. [Précède un déterm. au pluriel ou bien un pronom]
>   a) Tous les, toutes les + substantif pluriel
>   L'ensemble de, la totalité de (personnes ou choses nombrables), sans exception. [[TLFi (Tous)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tous)]

Here, *tout* is an adjective, and fortunately it behaves normally: it is variable, so, since *les routes* is feminine and plural, *tout* becomes *toutes*.

As for Google translate: it is a really good piece of software, designed to provide its users with a *meaningful translation*, even if the input is not grammatically correct, which is great, since most of the actual language is not grammatically correct. As far as I know, it doesn't even know if what you give it is grammatically correct, it just tries to makes some sense of it. So that's no wonder it gives you a translation for both.

Comment: Yes, it was a bit difficult for me to understand whether route was masculine or feminine. TLF is a good resource, very useful indeed. Cheers!